# Close, minimize and maximize buttons randomly moved sides

Tags: 12.04, window-buttons

I turned my Ubuntu on this morning and for no reason the close, max and min buttons moved from the left side of the window to the right !!!

I don't know why but this happened to every theme (which is loads) on the PC.

Any one else had this ?, or know a fix ? cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fixed this..

First install this

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

Then open it

```
gconf-editor
```

Now click on`apps` then `metacity` then click `general`
button_
A dialog will open in the right of the window, now find the option `button_layout` and change the text next to it to `close,minimize,maximize` and this will fix it.

Also you can change the button order (eg minimize,maximize,close) if you wish.

Or add a drop down menu by doing this to put it in the right corner `minimize,maximize,close:menu` or `menu:minimize,maximize,close` for a left menu with buttons on the right.